# Unexpected strftime() behaviour on Python and macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-sierra, strftime

I'm obtaining inconsistent behaviour with the output of datetime.strftime().

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Python 3.6.2. I have a Python program, named `wut.py`, that is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime
import locale
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(locale.getlocale())
    print(datetime.today().strftime('%c'))
```

In a terminal, I write

```
$ date
Gio 24 Ago 2017 18:54:01 CEST
```

which is the Italian way of writing dates. Then

```
$ python3 ~/Desktop/wut.py 
('it_IT', 'UTF-8')
Thu Aug 24 18:54:03 2017
```

where the date and time are written in another locale. How is this happening? Is this a bug or is there any reason for this behaviour?

I'm puzzled because the Python docs mention that `%c` refers to "Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.", so I thought that the system's locale is the "appropriate" one ;) (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, sec 8.1.8)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but you say you are using python3 but your shebang calls out python 2... should be #!/usr/bin/python3

Comment: Can you see what the [C `strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) gives you? I think Python ultimately delegates to the C `strftime` to handle this.

Comment: @AllenMoh thanks, you're right, I've fixed it. Anyway, it should change nothing in the above example

Comment: If you "explicitly" set the locale to use your system locale with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`, you will get the expected Italian output. I don't know why this appears to be necessary.

Comment: @user2357112 How can I see what the C function gives me? `man strftime`  just says that `%c    is replaced by national representation of time and date.` and that `the strftime() function uses the current locale`

Comment: @LordM'zn: By writing, compiling, and executing a C program that uses the C function.

Comment: @chepner you're right, thank you. I added 'locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')' before the last time, and the output is now `Gio 24 Ago 19:27:59 2017`

Comment: Another thing to check would be to call `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)` (in Python) and see what locale that gives you.

Comment: @user2357112 I've checked the C function output with the following
`#include <ctime>
    #include <iostream>
    int main(void) {
        using namespace std;
        time_t t = time(nullptr);
        char mbstr[100];
        if (strftime(mbstr, sizeof(mbstr), "%c", localtime(&t))) {
            cout << mbstr << '\n';
        }
    }`

and then `g++ -o ~/Desktop/wut.out ~/Desktop/wut.cpp; ~/Desktop/./wut.out` gives `Thu Aug 24 19:37:21 2017`
PS sorry, I'm not very familiar with SO formatting :|

Comment: @user2357112 I also checked `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)` and it prints `('it_IT', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Weird. `locale.getlocale` is behaving like the locale has been set, but functions that use the locale are behaving like it hasn't been set.

Comment: Does calling `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)` have any effect on `strftime` behavior?

Comment: It seems to have no effect, still printing `Thu Aug 24 20:01:16 2017`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into the `locale` module a bit, I find this under the description of `getdefaultlocale()`:

> According to POSIX, a program which has not called
>           setlocale(LC_ALL, "") runs using the portable 'C' locale.
>           Calling setlocale(LC_ALL, "") lets it use the default locale as
>           defined by the LANG variable. Since we don't want to interfere
>           with the current locale setting we thus emulate the behavior
>           in the way described above.

From this, I gather it is good practice to call

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

to set your locale to the one you expect to inherit from the caller's evironment. Do that, and you should get the expected output from `strftime`.

---

That said, I noticed a difference in behavior between Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 on my macOS 10.12 installation. On startup, `locale.getdefaultlocale()` and `locale.getlocale()` both return `('en_US', 'UTF-8')` in Python 3. In Python 2, though, `getlocale()` returns `(None, None)` until I call `setlocale`. In either case, the call to `setlocale` is still required for `strftime` to actually use the set locale, rather than the default `C` locale. I do not know if this represents a bug, or if so, which one is the buggy instance.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was puzzled by the behaviour of locale.getlocale() in python3, that returns a non-empty value even if you haven't set any locale yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different locale categories that are all configured independently, and `locale.getlocale()` only gets you the settting of the `LC_CTYPE` category. Time formatting is controlled by the `LC_TIME` category, which you can check with `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)`.

You can use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` to set the settings for all locale categories to the user's default settings (typically specified in the `LANG` environment variable). `setlocale` isn't threadsafe, so this usually goes near the start of a program.

Answer (score -1):

The Python result is correct. `strftime('%c')` returns same result format.